Resolving Several Errors for a Line of Code in GAMS software
I have several errors in the following line:
e3_d(b).. sum( (t)$(ord(t) >= 1) and (ord(t) <= t-N_chp_on_max+N_chp_on_max), alpha(b, t) ) =l= N_chp_on_max;
Two errors (',' expected) and (Unknown symbol) for and,
The error (Set identifier or quoted element expected) for ord,
Additionally, for N_chp_on_max, it gives the errors (Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less indices as declared) and (Incompatible operands for addition).
It also gives the error (Incompatible operands for addition) for the last closing parenthesis of the first part of sum.
For the comma before alpha, it gives the following errors:
('=l=' or '=e=' or '=g=' operator expected)
(Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again)
I would greatly appreciate it if you could guide me and help me resolve this problem.

Looks like two smaller issue:

A missing pair of parentheses in the $ condition
The card operator was missing in the $ condition (at least I assume that this is what you had in mind)

So, the following should work:
e3_d(b).. sum( (t)$((ord(t) >= 1) and (ord(t) <= card(t)-N_chp_on_max+N_chp_on_max)), alpha(b, t) ) =l= N_chp_on_max;

